# How to disconnect Windows Phone 8.1 emulator from network?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, emulation, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-sl-8.1

I want to test my app when it is disconnected from network (Internet connection). How to simulate the scenario in which phone doesn't have an Internet connection?

Comment: Have you tried to turn on the *Airplane mode*? Is it sufficient?

Comment: @Romasz: Airplane mode is not the right way of doing it. What if I need mobile-network if internet is not available? Probably to send SMS instead of message from my app?

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why I've asked if it's suffiectent for you. In some cases this can be a fast way to check the situation 'no any network'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. Go to **Network** tab of the emulator's **Additional Tools**.
2. Check **Enable Network Simulation** to test your app with different
   network speeds and different signal strengths.
3. In the **Network Speed** dropdown list, select the option: **No network**
4. Click **Refresh**

Comment: This was not working at first. Restarted the PC and now its working!