# Windows Phone 8.1 emulator check Internet connection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, emulation

I need to test my app in emulator, check Internet connection.
I am using following class (from here http://www.jayway.com/2015/04/23/how-to-verify-internet-access-in-universal-apps/):

```
public class Connection
{
    public static bool HasInternetAccess { get; private set; }

    public Connection() {
        NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformationOnNetworkStatusChanged;
        CheckInternetAccess();
    }

    private void NetworkInformationOnNetworkStatusChanged(object sender) {
        CheckInternetAccess();
    }

    private void CheckInternetAccess() {
        var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        HasInternetAccess = (connectionProfile != null &&
                             connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() ==
                             NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
    }
}
```

and checking connection by using class:

```
Connection conn = new Connection();
if (Connection.HasInternetAccess) {
      // some code
} else {
      MessageDialog msgbox = new MessageDialog("no internet");
      await msgbox.ShowAsync();
}
```

Problem is I get true every time, in emulator.
I tried solution from here [How to disconnect Windows Phone 8.1 emulator from network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847408/how-to-disconnect-windows-phone-8-1-emulator-from-network), even rebooted PC, but nothing changed.

Testing on the device was correct. True if connection enabled, false if connection disabled.

P.S. Sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 1):

The emulator always returns NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile() as true, even if you emulate network conditions as having no network.

Use physical device to test the app.(it will works fine).